# How can you express to the creator that you enjoyed a book/performance/album?

Tags: phrase-requests

Say I'm writing a message (on twitter) to an author of a book you read, or a message to an artist about live you went to or album you listened to.

I want to talk/ask about something else, but I want to start of with that I enjoyed the work.

The English equivalent would be "I thought it was very interesting/I enjoyed it very much/It was a wonderful performance/etc"

I looked up "to enjoy" in an English-Japanese dic and all I got was 楽しむ and it doesn't seem quite right in this situation.
楽しみにしています　I know exists but is "I'm looking forward to it".

How can you say you enjoyed the book/performance/album? Any variants or example more specific statements would be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some examples

素晴らしい◯◯でした。(** was wonderful.)

感動しました。(moved me)

最高でした。(was the best)

if its an album,

いつも聞いています。(I always listen to it)

if its a book, depending on the content

私のバイブルです(Its my bible) not literally, but you know.

if using slang is ok, now a days people put(神)before book/performance/album before and call it divine. Its a internet thing so depending on who it is it might kinda be inappropriate though.